# How long should TopicClient live for?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, cloud, azureservicebus

When publishing messages to an Azure ServiceBus Topic in a pub/sub scenario, I am currently holding onto and reusing an instance of

`Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.TopicClient`

I have wrapped the creation and usage of it in a component that implements IDisposable so that the TopicClient can be closed on disposing, however I am not sure about the cost if any, of maintaining the connection to the ServiceBus.

Is this considered best practice when sending multiple messages over time or should I create a new client for each message?

MSDN is not helpful on this apart from the section on Thread Safety: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.topicclient.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure about best practice but in, for example, the code of NServiceBus the only check that I saw was that a TopicClient might be closed and after that they create a new one, otherwise they'll re-use an older one. See: https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.AzureServiceBus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TopicClient/QueueClient is relatively cheap to create and hold, as the connection is maintained by the MessagingFactory under the hood. The connection may be wound down if there are no clients left, so it's better to hold on to the client for as long as you need it and feasibly can. Avoiding making new clients and reusing existing ones is good.

It's ok to use the client from multiple threads and you can also send/receive concurrently without setting locks. That's what the thread-safety section is trying to telegraph.

Comment: You wouldn't believe it! Just before I read your answer (and questioned your authority - sorry), I loaded a Channel 9 video on Azure Event Hub (https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Europe/2014/CDP-B307?ocid=player). Who started the introduction? Clemens Vasters. I assume this is you.

Comment: That is me, indeed :)